# plot one polygon from a spatial polygon data frame

Tags: r, polygon, crop, raster, shapefile

I'm a bit new to R and so this mights seem an easy command for you. I have a shapefile loaded in R with several polygons in it, and I just would like to plot the first polygon. I tried several commands but it's not working.

My aim is to crop a raster with that first element of my shapefile, again I tried several stuff but it's not working..

I hope I'm clear,

Thanks a lot!

Jude

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your polygons are called `pols`, this should work for you:

`plot(pols[1,])`

A spatial polygon dataframe is just like any other df in this case, with each row corresponding to a feature. So if you want to subset it, you can use ordinary indexing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was easier than I thought indeed. I have another question then what does "@" do for polygons then?

Comment: The `@` operator lets you access slots in the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` class object. You can have a look at the slots with the `str()` function